# No greatest real number $p$ such that $p^2 < 2$.

Tags: real-analysis

On page 2 or Rudin, we're told that the set $A = \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: p^2 < 2\}$ has no greatest element since if $p \in A$,

$$q = p - \frac{p^2 -2}{p+2} > 0$$

and a little algebra shows that $q^2 < 2$.

Rudin then makes the following remark, which I found puzzling

"The purpose of the above discussion has been to show that the rational number system has certain gaps, in spite of the fact that between any two rational there is another"

The reason I find this confusing is because even in $\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{p \in \mathbb{R}: p^2 < 2\}$ has no greatest element.  What "gaps" is Rudin referring to?

Comment: He’s merely saying that there are rationals whose square is less than $2$, others whose square is greater, but none for which it’s equal to $2$.

Comment: I think the best thing to say here is that the gaps are the "intermediate values" in the failure of the intermediate value theorem to hold over $\bf Q$.

Comment: Note that the statement would be the same, but perhaps clearer, if Rudin wrote $$A = \{p\in\mathbb Q:p^2\leq 2\}$$

Comment: Relevant: http://abstrusegoose.com/12 Like other comments already mentioned, he just meant to argue that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete. As you said $\{p \in \mathbb{R}: p^2 < 2\}$ has no greatest element either, but the supremum of this set is in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For the two comments above, a combined answer? I think they address the question well.

Comment: Your displayed inequality for $q$ is wrong. For example, let $p=-\frac 43,$ which is in $A$. Then $q=-1$, which is not positive.